# Terminal is not starting after sudo passwd -d ahmad

Tags: debian, terminal, login

I am running debian 10 and Terminal not starting after below lines...

Also Xterm and Xuterm is not starting.

What should i do to reverse this action

```
passwd -d ahmad
usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin ahmad
chage -l ahmad
grep ahmad /etc/passwd
grep ahmad /etc/shadow
```

Comment: You've set the login shell to prevent a shell starting. Are you asking how to revert this setting?

Comment: If that is it so yes please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the login shell to prevent a shell starting. (I'm not sure why you would have run this command if you didn't know what it does. It's pretty specific; did someone trick you into trying this?)

Assuming you're on a platform that has `/bin/bash` you can use this to reset your shell

```
usermod -s /bin/bash ahmad
```

By the way, the `passwd -d` removed the password from your account. If you're on a system that has any possibility of remote access I would recommend you set a password:

```
passwd    # Run this as user ahmad. If you're root use "passwd ahmad" instead
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick wise notice. @-}---

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by editing /etc/passwd file in TTY shell login by pressing alt + Cntrl + Fn + F2
i Deleted the /usr/sbin/nologin in front of ahmad ( my username)
and it worked well so far.